# Magento: Get simple product color from custom table

Tags: function, magento, colors, enterprise

I'm really struggling with this in Magento 1.10 Enterprise. I have a array of simple products color ids and I want to use this id to query the atb_color table. Raw query:

```
SELECT description FROM atb_colors WHERE option_id = 'my_color_id'
```

Here is a method I was trying to build:

```
public function getColorData($product){ 
    $ids = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();    
    foreach($ids as $id){
        $simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
                    -->Query using my_color_id

    }       
}
```

I can use this to get name and quantity. If I put this in the foreach loop:

```
echo $simpleproduct->getName()." - ".(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleproduct)->getQty() . '<br />';
```

How would I run this query. Forgive me I am very new to Magento. It's somewhat difficult to grasp some of it. But I'm on a deadline to finish this one section of displaying color and size. Any help? Please, please!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the weirdest hack, but if you are really in big hurry

```
public function getProductCustomColor($product)
{
    $ids = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
    foreach($ids as $id){
        $simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        $select = $product->getResource()->getReadConnection()->select()
            ->from('atb_colors', array('description'))
            ->where('option_id = :my_color_id');
        $colorDescription = $product->getResource()->getReadConnection()
            ->fetchOne($select, array('option_id' => $simpleProduct->getYourColorId()));
        // ...
    }
}
```

To everyone: **never write code for magento in this way**.